# cakephp 3 add default class to inputs

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

i'm trying to add a default class for each input in my cakephp 3 app.
Example of what i want:

Input:
`<echo $this->Form->control('email');`

Output:
`<input class="form-control" class="is-invalid"/>`

Desired output:
`<input class="form-control is-invalid"/>`

for this i have edited input template of FormHelper

```
$this->viewBuilder()->setHelpers([
        'Form' => [
            'templates' => [
                'input' => '<input class="form-control" type="{{type}}" name="{{name}}"{{attrs}}/>'
            ]
        ]
    ]);
```

the problem is that `{{attrs}}` possibly contain others classes. Do you have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved :D
create a FormHelper to override method control and add class.

```
class BootstrapFormHelper extends FormHelper{
    public function control($fieldName, array $options = []){
        if($this->request->is('post') && !$this->isFieldError($fieldName)){
            $options['class'] = 'form-control is-valid';
        }else{
            $options['class'] = 'form-control';
        }
        return parent::control($fieldName, $options);
    }
}
```

then change your AppView

```
class AppView extends View{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->loadHelper(
            'Form', [
                'className' => 'BootstrapForm',
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: There's also plugins available that aid with creating bootstrap compatible output: **https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/awesome-cakephp#templating**.

Comment: hi i know but the plugins work with bootstrap 3 only. I'm using bootstrap 4, it's have a lot of changes.

Comment: The `develop` branch of https://github.com/friendsofcake/bootstrap-ui supports bootstrap 4.

Comment: Where would this helper go?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Matoran's answer, I also checked to see if there was another 'class' provided when the form control element was created and include that with the override class. For me I still want `form-control` as a class but also needed to add the class `datepicker` or `datetimepicker` while I was generating the form.

```
class BootstrapFormHelper extends FormHelper{
    public function control($fieldName, array $options = []){
        if($this->request->is('post') && !$this->isFieldError($fieldName)){
            $options['class'] = (isset($options['class'])) ? 'form-control is-valid '.$options['class'] : 'form-control is-valid';
        }else{
            $options['class'] = (isset($options['class'])) ? 'form-control '.$options['class'] : 'form-control';
        }
        return parent::control($fieldName, $options);
    }
}
```