# CakePHP 3.x - Add class to form input after template

Tags: forms, templates, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Using a [form template file](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses) I made sure each form input would automatically have the form-control class, saving me some code further on.
The relevant template item is:

```
    'input' => '<input type="{{type}}" name="{{name}}" class="form-control"{{attrs}}/>',
```

This works like a charm, except when I want to add another class to a specific input. With this set-up the additional class gets ignored.

Question: **how can I make it so I can add additional classes next to the standard classes?**

Comment: Reads just like **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46505025/cakephp-3-add-default-class-to-inputs**.

Comment: Yes, sorry, couldn't find it while searching. However, I don't like the approach as I would have to put all the additional classes in this helper extension. Isn't there a more direct solution?

Comment: No, there isn't. Instead of `=` you could simply apply `class` option defaults and use `.=` to append the `form-control` class, or use one of the plugins that I linked in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for the addition. Could you elaborate on that last part? Can I edit default options without changing the template then?

Comment: You mean the plugins? No, but they will inject the bootstrap classes for you out of the box.

Comment: I was unclear, I meant the other part. Could you elaborate on "Instead of = you could simply apply class option defaults and use .= to append the form-control class"

Comment: I meant to set a default value for `class` in the `$options` array, like `null` or an empty string, and append your custom class instead of overwriting the option. However looks like the helper already has a method for doing that, [**`Helper::addClass()`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.5.3/src/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L2603).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155812/discussion-between-roberto-and-ndm).